# error when trying to login by the NEXT Credentials

Tags: linux

I got the below error when trying to login by the NEXT Credentials

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information?

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

working fine after adding the proxy by the below command

ncli proxy add name=any_name address=my_proxy_IP port=proxy_port proxy-types=http,https